# Checking the current time on an ESX server from the vSphere client

Tags: linux, vmware-esx, time

What is the easiest way to check the current time on an ESX server from a machine which has the vSphere infrastructure client installed on it ?

In other words, is there any way to get the current time on an ESX server if you dont have the root credentials of the server ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out time of ESX server with vSphere infrastructure client, you could try to log in to VI client, in left pane click on your hypervisor, in right pane click on 'Configuration' tab and then in 'Software' area click on 'Time Configuration'. Then you could see the actual time on hypervisor. I'm not sure if your user account has enough permissions for this operations, but you could try... ;)